# MLE and non-normality

Tags: maximum-likelihood, asymptotics

What is a non-trivial example of an identifiable model whose MLE is consistent, but the MLE's asymptotic distribution is not normal? Parametric setting and IID sample would be desirable.

Comment: Does $X_i$ i.i.d Uniform on $(0,\theta)$ count as non-trivial?

Comment: It certainly does! And thank you for being such a stubborn and intelligent bunch of atoms. ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To develop StubbornAtom's comment,  if $X_i$ is i.i.d. uniformly distributed on $[0,\theta]$

and you have $n$ samples then the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$ is $\hat{\theta}_n=\max\limits_{1\le i \le n}X_i$.

$\hat{\theta}_n$ has a $\mathrm{Beta}(n,1)$ distribution scaled by $\theta$.

As $n$ increases, $n\left(\theta-\hat \theta_n\right)$ converges in distribution to $\mathrm{Exp}\left(\frac1\theta\right)$, not a normal distribution.

or in a handwaving sense, for large $n$, the maximum likelihood estimator $\hat{\theta}_n$ approximately has a reversed and shifted exponential distribution with density $\frac{n x^{n-1}}{\theta^n} \approx \frac n{\theta} \exp\left(\frac{nx}{\theta}-n\right)$ when $0 < x \le \theta$ looking like

[image: reversed and shifted exponential distribution]

Answer (score 9):

Theorems showing asymptotic normality of the MLE generally hinge on the MLE being in in the interior of the parameter space and the information function existing.  [Moran (1971)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/abs/maximumlikelihood-estimation-in-nonstandard-conditions/DCD37A255226CCE49CB765F79FB4D44B) examines the MLE under non-standard conditions, including when the parameter is on the boundary.  That might be a good place to look if you would like a non-trivial example.

Comment: Thanks, Ben! I'll check the reference.