# Consistency vs. unbiasdness

Tags: maximum-likelihood, unbiased-estimator, consistency

What is the difference between

$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \ \mathrm{E}_{\theta}(T_n(X)) = \theta$

and

$ T_n(X) \xrightarrow{p} \theta \ $  for  $\ n \xrightarrow{} \infty$ ?

(unbiasdness vs. Consisteny)

---

Ups... there seems to be this question already :-(
[Similar CrossValidated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31036/what-is-the-difference-between-a-consistent-estimator-and-an-unbiased-estimator?rq=1)

Shall I delete this question?

Comment: There's no problem, Michael: duplicates actually serve a useful purpose in that they sometime express the same question in different ways, increasing the chance of good hits in future searches.

Comment: @whuber - This isn't actually a duplicate, as this question is about asymptotic unbiasedness and consistency, not unbiasedness (a small-sample property) and consistency.

Comment: Hmmm... this leads me to something else: Do you have a nice example, where you don't have unbiasdness for small samples, but asymptotic unbiasdness? I have problems to see why this can happen...

Comment: @jbowman You are right; thank you.  I simply accepted the OP's assessment of the duplicate nature.  I believe this question has been discussed elsewhere on CV approximately 18 months ago; it's worth [a search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=unbiased+consistency+asymptotic).

Comment: Michael, it depends on what you mean by "small samples." If you set a fixed threshold between "small" and not "small," then examples are easy to come by: simply switch from an unbiased estimator when the sample is "small" to an asymptotically biased estimator when the sample is not "small."

Comment: Here's an answer to a related question that may help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239146/consistency-and-asymptotically-unbiasedness