# Bias of the maximum likelihood estimator of an exponential distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, bias, exponential-distribution

The maximum likelihood estimator of an exponential distribution $f(x, \lambda) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ is $\lambda_{MLE} = \frac {n} {\sum x_i}$; I know how to derive that by find the derivative of the log likelihood and setting equal to zero.

I then read in an online article that "Unfortunately this estimator is clearly biased since $<\sum_i x_i>$ is indeed $1/\lambda$ but $<1/\sum_i x_i > \neq \lambda$."

Why does $<\sum_i x_i> = 1/\lambda$? If I am correct in deducing the $< >$ operator means expected value, then I thought $E(x_i) = 1/\lambda$ - that is, the expected value of one such $x_i$, is $1/\lambda$, not the sum of all $x_i$'s. And can someone explain the second of the statement and how these two statements demonstrate the MLE is biased?

Comment: It's a bit tricky to say there's an error when we don't know what $<.>$ means (context might help), but indeed it must be the case that since $\bar x$ is unbiased for $1/\lambda$ that $1/\bar x$ will be biased; it's a consequence of Jensen's inequality. This is not necessarily a problem, most MLEs are biased; it's not clear to me that unbiasedness is especially important (generally I'd tend to think something more like low MSE would be more important than unbiasedness).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I cannot speak as to the use of these symbols but let me show you instead the traditional way, why the mle is biased.

Recall that the exponential distribution is a special case of the General Gamma distribution with two parameters, shape $a$ and rate $b$. The pdf of a Gamma Random Variable is:

$$f_Y (y)= \frac{1}{\Gamma(a) b^a} y^{a-1} e^{-y/b}, \ 0<y<\infty$$

where $\Gamma (.)$ is the gamma function. Alternative parameterisations exist, see for example [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution).

If you put $a=1$ and $b=1/\lambda$ you arrive at the pdf of the exponential distribution:

$$f_Y(y)=\lambda e^{-\lambda y},0<y<\infty$$

One of the most important properties of a gamma RV is the additivity property, simply put that means that if $X$ is a $\Gamma(a,b)$ RV, $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is also a Gamma RV with $a^{*}=\sum a_i$ and $b^{*}=b$ as before.

Define $Y=\sum X_i$ and as noted above $Y$ is also a Gamma RV with shape parameter equal to $n$, $\sum_{i=1}^n 1 $, that is and rate parameter $1/\lambda$ as $X$ above. Now take the expectation $E[Y^{-1}]$

$$ E\left  [ Y^{-1} \right]=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{y^{-1}y^{n-1}\lambda^n}{\Gamma(n)}\times e^{-\lambda y}dy=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{y^{n-2}\lambda^n}{\Gamma(n)}\times e^{-\lambda y}dy$$

Comparing the latter integral with an integral of a Gamma distribution with shape parameter $n-1$ and rate one $1/\lambda$ and using the fact that $\Gamma(n)=(n-1) \times \Gamma(n-1)$ we see that it equals $\frac{\lambda}{n-1}$. Thus

$$E\left[ \hat{\theta} \right]=E\left[ \frac{n}{Y} \right]=n \times E\left[Y^{-1}\right]=\frac{n}{n-1} \lambda$$

which clearly shows that the mle is biased. Note, however, that the mle **is consistent**. We also know that under some regularity conditions, the mle is asymptotically efficient and normally distributed, with mean the true parameter $\theta$ and variance $\{nI(\theta) \}^{-1} $. It is therefore an optimal estimator.

Does that help?

Comment: Also note that the MLE is asymptotically unbiased in the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @BrianBorchers, that's what JohnK meant by "consistent."

Comment: @TheBigAmbiguous yes, but it wasn't clear to me that the original poster would understand that.

Comment: (+1) John, for the thoroughness. I would only suggest that you change notation for the parameters - the $(a,b)$ notation for the gamma distribution is in many corners used for the "shape, rate" parametrization, rather than for the "shape, scale" one - and the wikipedia page you link to, attests to that.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Thank you for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: @TheBigAmbiguous, JohnK, and BrianBorchers: *Asymptotically unbiased* and *consistent* are not synonyms (and neither implies the other). Let's try not to confuse them, for the sake of clarity. JohnK, note also that consistency is not a particularly strong property, so it doesn't say much regarding "optimality" of any type.

Comment: @cardinal Thank you for your comment. I was implying that mle is optimal because of its asymptotic properties, consistency being one of them but also asymptotic efficiency and normality. I will edit that sentence to make note of these important facts.

Comment: @cardinal, It was my understanding that consistency implies asymptotic-unbiasedness. Do you have a counterexample demonstrating that this is untrue?

Comment: @TheBigAmbiguous: Sure. See [this comment](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31036/what-is-the-difference-between-a-consistent-estimator-and-an-unbiased-estimator#comment60184_31038) and the related discussion.