# Poisson regression intercept downward bias when true intercepts are small

Tags: bias, poisson-regression, intercept

When fitting a Poisson regression on data with low expected values, the intercept term has a small bias even when the model is perfectly specified. Below, I simulated data just using $y \sim rPois(exp(\beta_0))$ and then fit the data using the glm model $log(E[y]) \sim \beta_0$. On average, the estimates are slightly biased downwards. The bias is small, but I would like to understand why this happens.

I could understand why this would happen if $\beta_0$ was a large negative number and the data were mostly zeros, but the data from the $\beta_0$ values I chose is always mostly non-zero. Why would this happen?

```
# function to run the simulation for one set of beta values
    run_sim <- function(b0, n = 50, R = 10000){
      
      # simulate y values and then estimate
      b0_estimates <- sapply(1:R, function(i){
        y = rpois(n, exp(b0))
        tmp = data.frame(y = rpois(n, exp(b0)))
        mod_col <- glm('y ~ 1', data = tmp, family=poisson)
        b0_hat <- mod_col$coefficients[1]
        return(b0_hat)
      })
      
      # get the bias
      mean_bias = mean(b0_estimates) - b0
      
      return(mean_bias)
    }
    
    # simulate for beta0 values ranging from 1 to 10
    b0_vec = 1:10
    bias_vec = sapply(b0_vec, function(b0){
      run_sim(b0, R = 10000)
    })
    
    # plot the results
    plot(b0_vec, bias_vec, xlab = 'true b0', ylab = 'b0 bias')
```

[image: Words]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The **score** function is exactly unbiased
$$E_{\beta_0}[\sum_i x_i(y_i-\mu_i)]=0$$
In your case that simplifies to
$$E_{\beta_0}[\sum y_i-\exp\beta_0]=0$$
The parameter estimate is a non-linear function of the score, so that tells us it won't be exactly unbiased.

Can we work out the direction of the bias? Well, the mean of $Y$ is $\exp \beta_0$, so $\beta_0=\log EY$ and $\hat\beta=\log \bar Y$. The logarithm function is concave, and $E[\bar Y]=E[Y]=\exp\beta_0$ so we can use Jensen's inequality to see that the bias is downward. (Or draw a picture, like the one [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/489912/showing-bias-of-mle-for-exponential-distribution-is-frac-lambdan-1) only the other way up)

Comment: Thank you! This is clear and helpful. I have two follow up questions: 

1) Is there a way to calculate the bias/Jensen's gap in this case? I.e. calculate $E[\hat{\beta_0}] - \beta_0$. It should be some function of $n$ and $\beta_0$. I am having trouble dealing with the distribution of $\log \bar{Y}$,

Comment: 2) The downward bias on the intercept term is still present when there are other coefficients in the model. How can we show this is due to Jensen's inequality in a similar way? When I try to show it similarly I end up with $\beta_0 = log E[\bar{Y}] - \beta_1 X_1 - \beta_2 X_2 - ...$ and $E[\hat{\beta}_0] = E[\log (n\bar{Y})] - E[\log(\sum_{i=1}^n exp(\hat{\beta}_1 X_{i1} + \hat{\beta}_2 X_{i2} + ...))]$. I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: You can't just use Jensen's inequality when it's a multidimensional problem. In fact, the bias is typically not defined when you have a covariate, because there's a tiny but non-zero probability that $\hat\beta$ is infinite